# RadioGroup not responding in onCheckedChanged

Tags: android, radio-group

I have the following code :

```
private void inflateCustomView()
    {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customNav = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);

    //Bind to its state change
    RadioGroup radioGrp = ((RadioGroup)customNav.findViewById(R.id.radio_nav));
    radioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
        {
            switch(checkedId)
            {
            case R.id.moneyRadioBtn:
                    isInCashMode = true;
                    break;
            case R.id.unitRadioBtn:
                    isInCashMode = false;
                    break;
            }

            setCashOrUnits(isInCashMode);
        }
    });

    //Attach to the action bar
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    }
```

The custom view seems to be correctly added but onCheckedChanged is never called. I tried inserting a breakpoint inside onCheckedChanged , but it was never reached. What am I doing wrong?

edit:
Here's the XML of the custom_view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_nav"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/moneyRadioBtn"
            android:text="Kr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

        />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/unitRadioBtn"
            android:text="Enheder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure you working with RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener. 
Please use new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() instead of only new OnCheckedChangeListener().
I see someone have the same problem in here :
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/PemtaXI9tpg

Answer (score 0):

Check with below code...

```
    RadioGroup radioGrp = ((RadioGroup)customNav.findViewById(R.id.radio_nav));
int checkedRadioButtonID = radioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
                {
                    switch(checkedId)
                    {
                    case R.id.moneyRadioBtn:
                            isInCashMode = true;
                            break;
                    case R.id.unitRadioBtn:
                            isInCashMode = false;
                            break;
                    }

                    setCashOrUnits(isInCashMode);
                }
            });
```

Notice,

```
radioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
```

Hope, this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this also.

```
radioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {

        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroup
                .getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        if (radioButton.getText().equals("radiobutton name")) {
            isInCashMode = true;
        } else {
            isInCashMode = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Just try. it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably paste in your XML layout, sometimes there can be problems there that stop the Radio Group from picking up the buttons within.

It's been a while since I worked with them, but I believe in the XML that Buttons have to be directly under the parent RadioGroup in XML, so if you have for example, a RadioButton within a LinearLayout within a RadioGroup, the RadioGroup won't pick up the button because it's not a direct child.

Edit: An alternative is to get a reference to each individual RadioButton in your code, define a CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener to handle the event, and then call

```
myRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myOnCheckChangeListener);
```

for each of them. A bit clunky (you'll have to manually get the id of the checked view in the onCheckedChanged() method) but it works!

Comment: I tried this and nothing. Maybe it's that I don't understand the intricacy of RadioGroups and listeners. Could it be a problem with the layout inflation and not being able to set up a listener to an inflated view? Or is the ActionBar overriding "clicks" on it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today and as nonsensical as it seems:

It requires CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener. RadioGroup blatantly refuses to accept RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener but works fine with the CheckBox one.

I don't even KNOW what is going on but it works like this. Barely.

Comment: You may want to turn this into a question of its own. There s gotta be something wrong with your XML